# Добавление title в SVG средствами JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Как с помощью JS добавить правильно к элементам SVG `<title>`, чтобы визуально появлялось сообщение, размещенное внутри *tooltip*?
SVG грузится , а не рисуется на JS.

```
<object id="idImageSVG" class="svgClass" /object>
```

Добавлять *tooltip* в *runtime*, а не встраивать в SVG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это в данном вопросе без разницы, как вы добавляете svg в HTML.
Если вы добавляете файл svg, через `object`, то потом будете использовать элементы svg внутри HTML странички через команду `use`

Главное, чтобы, код реализующий `title` svg был рабочим. А каким способом вы его добавите не имеет значения. Либо в самом файле svg, либо динамически c помощью `JS`

**Чтобы тултип срабатывал необходимо его разместить внутри тега группы `<g>`**

Пример создания svg tooltip. Удерживайте курсор на фигурах до появления тултипа

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg  width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<g id="titleRect">
<title> Это зеленый квадрат </title>
<rect id="rect1" x="10" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="yellowgreen" /> 
</g>

<g id="titleCircle">
<title> Это пурпурный круг  </title>
<circle id="circle1" cx="200" cy="150" r="50"  fill="purple" /> 
</g>


</svg>
```

Добавление svg файлов в HTML:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg" width="200" height="200" >
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Другие [способы](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047) добавления svg в HTML

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То что нужно. Дальше разберусь

Comment: @Deniskins благодарю Команда `object` у вас в вопросе немного неточна, сейчас добавлю вниз ответа